# Applescript to Save File as Two Separate File Formats with Fixed Extensions

Tags: macos, file, applescript, photoshop, finder

I often need to save a screenshot of an art file as two different files. The first would be a PDF with a **"_prv"** at the end of the file name. The second would be a JPG with an **"_thm"** file name.

So, examples of file names would be:

```
1733419_prv.pdf
1733419_thm.jpg
```

The **"1733419"** part would be job-specific, and it would be nice if the script would prompt the user the enter that information. It would also be nice if the script could prompt the user for the location that the new files should be saved to.

Is this all possible as an applescript or possibly a Photoshop script?

Thank you so much for any help!
Bryan

Comment: Your question is quite unclear... why do you want to make a screen-capture, is the application you are using incapable of saving the file itself properly? What application are you using? Who/what is supposed to ask you the job-reference number? Can your application generate one of the files itself and allow some automation to create the other one?

Comment: The reason for the screen capture is that the other two versions of the file are meant to be thumbnails of the original file. The thumbnails do not need to be as large as the original file. The screen capture, as you know, is nice and compact at 72DPI and still retains sharpness where resizing down in Photoshop may affect that. All of the art files are viewed in Photoshop. I have worked with scripts in the past that would prompt you for information, such as the job number in this particular instance. Not sure that I understand your last question, or else I certainly would address it.

Comment: Still not sure if I have got this right... so your originals are high resolution PSD files and you would be viewing them in Photoshop. Then you would like something to pop up and ask you the job reference and you would enter it in a dialog box then it would generate two 72 dpi files, one a PDF and the other a JPEG. Is that correct? How did you envisage the above-described process would start - by going to Photoshop's File->Scripts menu, or by double-clicking something in Finder or other?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The originals are high res PSD files.

Comment: What I was hoping could happen would be that the screenshot would still be taken manually. After the screenshot is taken, the user would drag the PNG file to the script which would then create the two thumbnails. The script would prompt the user for the job number, then save the two files. Does this all make sense? I realize it's a bit convoluted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I have improved the script a little. It will now do nothing and exit gracefully if you select `Cancel` when entering the Job Reference number. It will also now handle spaces in the Job Reference number. It also creates an output directory on your Desktop, so if you enter a Job Reference number of `1234` you will see a directory (folder) called `1234` appear on your Desktop which contains the 2 output files.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ask user for job reference, store in $ref
ref=$(osascript -e 'Tell application "System Events" to display dialog "Enter Job Reference:" default answer ""' -e 'text returned of result' 2>/dev/null)

# Quit without doing anything if user didn't enter anything
[ -z "$ref" ] && exit

# Make a place for the output files
DIRECTORY="$HOME/Desktop/$ref"
mkdir "$DIRECTORY" 2> /dev/null   # Don't worry if it already exists
cd "$DIRECTORY"

# Get user to select area to grab, then save as JPEG
screencapture -i -t jpg "${ref}_thm.jpg"

# Convert JPEG to PDF
sips -s format pdf "${ref}_thm.jpg" --out "${ref}_prv.pdf" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

**Original Answer**

I hope this is close to what you mean. Save it in your HOME directory as `grab`, then start Terminal and type:

```
chmod +x grab
```

which will make the file executable.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ask user for job reference, store in $ref
ref=$(osascript -e 'Tell application "System Events" to display dialog "Enter Job Reference:" default answer ""' -e 'text returned of result' 2>/dev/null)

# Get user to click on a window to grab, then save as JPG
screencapture -w -i -t jpg ${ref}_thm.jpg

# Convert JPG to PDF
sips -s format pdf ${ref}_thm.jpg --out ${ref}_prv.pdf > /dev/null 2>&1
```

You can now either type:

```
./grab
```

or double-click on the file called `grab` in the Finder.

It will ask you for a job reference and then start the screen grab. You should click on a window to tell it which one you mean. It will then create the two files you asked for.

The advantage of this method is that no extra software is required to be installed - such as ImageMagick or anything since it uses built-in OSX tools only.

Comment: Thank you - I'm eager to try this, but am unsure of the process. I saved the script as a text file in my Home folder..called "grab". Then, I typed the "chmod +x grab" command in Terminal. Terminal just said that there is "No such file or directory". Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Your text editor may have added an extension like `.txt` or something. In the Terminal, type `ls grab*` and it will list all the files. You should see one called `grab.txt` or some such, you can rename it so it doesn't have an extension like this: `mv  grab.txt  grab`. Then carry on with the `chmod...` thing.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to change the grab document's format to an executable, but after launching the exe..it doesn't look like it's going to work. I double-clicked it and it just appears to error out. This is the text..
CLEMD-A03485:~ e0012245$ /Volumes/Work/Users/e0012245/grab ; exit;
/Volumes/Work/Users/e0012245/grab: line 1: {rtf1ansiansicpg1252cocoartf1187cocoasubrtf400: command not found
/Volumes/Work/Users/e0012245/grab: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
/Volumes/Work/Users/e0012245/grab: line 2: `{\fonttbl\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Consolas;}'
logout

[Process completed]

Comment: Your text editor has saved it as RTF format but it needs to be plain ASCII text not RTF.

Comment: If you can't get your editor to save straight, unformatted text instead of RTF, you can carefully copy my code not inclusing any extraneous spaces or characters, and then go into Terminal and type `pbpaste > grab` and that will paste the copied code into a file called `grab`.

Comment: Mark - I took your suggestion about typing "mv grab.rtf grab" and that worked. That was before I received the error message, however. The "grab" file did not have an extension before it was converted to an executable.

Comment: And just to be clear, the error message was received when I double-clicked the grab file when it was an exe.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that your editor has saved it as RTF (Rich Text Format). If you are using `TextEdit` you can use the menu option `Format->Make Plain Text` at the top of the screen.

Comment: Ok, that worked..saving it out as plain text. This is pretty good! I do have a couple questions, however. Is there a way to have the screenshot be a user-defined selection? Think shift+command+4. Also, the jpg file is saving without the extension..can that be remedied?

Comment: Regarding your first point, remove the `-w` from the line starting `screencapture` as that is the bit that forces it to capture a whole `w`indow rather than a user-defined selection.

Comment: Not sure why the JPEG is saving without the extension - it gets one on my machine and, in fact, if it didn't have one, the last command would fail to convert it to a PDF. Maybe you have extensions suppressed in your Finder... try going into Finder and selecting Preferences->Advanced and turning on the `Show all filename extensions`

Comment: By the way, you can move the `grab` script to your Desktop with no loss of functionality if you wish.

Comment: Not sure why, but I'm having problems with changing the mode of the grab file to an executable (again). I changed the format of the text document to plain text, but the Terminal is saying that there is "no such file or directory" when trying the chmod command.

Comment: You can use `ls` in Terminal to see the files in the current folder. Or, if you want to be more specific, use `ls grab*` to see all files that start with `grab` followed by anything else. If you have moved `grab` to your Desktop, you will need to change directory in Terminal too, you can do that with `cd Desktop`. You can go back to your HOME directory (folder) by just typing `cd` with no parameters. You can see which directory (folder) you are in using `pwd` which `p`rints `w`orking `d`irectory.

Comment: It's absolutely perfect, Mark. You were right about the file extensions, too. Though, I'm not sure why the PDF would have the extension and the JPG wouldn't.